# Software to show amount of data transfer of each process

Tags: internet, network-monitoring

I am noticing some unusual network data transfer activity. Is there any software that can show the amount of network data transfer is process is doing.

Comment: Do you mean Disk I/O or network transfer (internet)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use **nethogs** to see the speed of transfer for each process.

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Run it in terminal by running `sudo nethogs` but if you have more than one network device, you may need to specify it like so:

```
sudo nethogs eth0
sudo nethogs eth1  
sudo nethogs wlan0  
sudo nethogs wlan1
```

A picture of nethogs working with a chrome opening a webpage:

[image: Nethogs in Action]

You also have **bmon** which shows you ethernet devide usage.

```
sudo apt-get install bmon
```

and just run it like `sudo bmon` it will show you all network devices are their usage
[image: BMON in Action]

Answer (score 7):

You can use a command line tool called **nethogs**.
First install it:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Then call it on the interface.Like this for Ethernet interface:

```
sudo nethogs eth0
```

It shows at what speed, processes are sending and receiving data.It may help you to find the unusual data transfer.