# Recommendations for a network monitoring data counter?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring

Is there a graphical data counter for Ubuntu that records how much uploaded/downloaded data was used and bandwidth being used and total amounts, filtering it by application?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291365/internet-traffic-monitor-for-ubuntu/291374#291374)

Comment: sOrry Any Other Alternate? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the program `nethogs` from the standard repository for this.

`sudo apt-get install nethogs`

`sudo nethogs` (it requires root privileges to run)

This tracks the network usage of all processes while it is running. When it starts it shows the current rate at which everything is sending/receiving, but you can press 'm' to switch it to cumulative amounts (and further times to display it as kB/B/MB). It will split sent/received data as well as show you a cumulative total across all processes from the time at which it was run.

Source: [Software to show amount of data transfer of each process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28912/software-to-show-amount-of-data-transfer-of-each-process?rq=1)

Comment: I Need Graphical Version Of Tool :(

Comment: Out of interest, is there any particular reason you need a graphical program as opposed to a terminal one? As far as I could see there weren't really any viable GUI options, and this seemed to best fit the bill for what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try WireShark.  Wireshark is a network tool that captures and analyzes packets off the wire. Wireshark can decode too many protocols.

For more information see WireShark's [Website](http://www.wireshark.org/)

To download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Its Very Hard To Use And When I`m Trying To Capture its displaying there are no interfaces on which capture can be done geting some sort of errors :(
i need a simple tool

Answer (score 1):

This won't list by application, but it does make graphs, which seem to be important to you, and you can get a pretty good idea about which apps are being nethogs by looking at the IP addresses—your mail uplink would be your mail client, web sites would likely be your browser, etc.

```
sudo apt-get install darkstat
sudo darkstat -i wwan0 4288
```

Then just browse to `http://localhost:4288` to see the graphs.

The command above assumes you want to track your mobile broadband usage, and that your 3G/4G modem uses the `wwan0` interface. If you want to track wifi, try `wlan0`, or type the command `ifconfig` to see which interfaces are available—they're the alphanumeric strings flushed to the left.